# Gmail API with heroku and django project

Tags: python, django, heroku, gmail-api

I am stuck with identyfing issue on application being deployed to Heroku. It is a python django project that using a Gmail API should send out emails to defined subscribers. Code is as below

views.py (where function is called)

```
def MailJournals(new_acts):
    mailAdresses = models.EmailSubscriber.objects.all().values_list('email')
    mail_list = [x[0] for x in mailAdresses]
    journal_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d/%m/%Y')

    message = MIMEText(render_to_string('newsScrapper/mail.html',{
    'journal_date': journal_date,
    'new_acts': new_acts,
}), 'html')

    message['to'] = ",".join(mail_list)
    message['from'] = EMAIL_HOST_USER
    message['subject'] = 'Official Journal as of ' + journal_date

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
        smtp.send_message(message)
```

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env('EMAIL_USERNAME')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
```

The thing is it perfectly works on localhost so I do not believe this is a code issue. Here are some heroku logs I have extracted for the call of that function:

> 2021-11-30T21:09:30.657994+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/home/load/" host=legisync.herokuapp.com request_id=6c5c138d-05a4-488e-8bcd-c0bdc03da7fa fwd="83.23.240.85" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=464ms status=302 bytes=259 protocol=https

Unfortunately I have no idea how to correctly identify underlying root cause why it does not work from heroku...
Any ideas, or if sth else is needed from my side to share pls let me know.

Comment: What is the issue exactly?  You state it works on localhost what is it doing hosted?  DO you have an error message?

Comment: the things is there is no error message, if there would be it would also probably appear on localhost as code issue, function runs on heroku but does not do what is supposed to do, so after clicking "load updates" that web scraps and emails to subscribers it only does web scraping part and does not send any email although the application does not crush, it is redirected back to "/home/" as it is supposed to do

Comment: so the bottom line is that it does not send email as it is supposed to send, it sends email only from localhost, when exactly same code is put on heroku, the function completes, it does not error but for whatever reason it will never send an email